# Can we classify all commutative unital algebras over the reals that are closed under $\sqrt{}$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Can we classify all finite dimensional commutative (but not necessarily associative) unital algebras over the reals in which every element is a square?

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by your axiom? To be closed under a law, the law should be defined, which is not the case for $\sqrt{}$.

Comment: @YCor see the edit.

Comment: Why vote down and close ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer for algebras which are additionally associative.

I'm interpreting the question as asking which such algebras have the property that every element of them is a square. I claim all such algebras are isomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$ for some $n$.

Firstly, since $-1$ must be a square, $\mathbb C$ embeds into this algebra, so we can in fact view it as an algebra over $\mathbb C$.

Next, I claim that this algebra is reduced. Any nilpotent $x$ must satisfy $x^n=0$ where $n$ is the dimension of this algebra, so we can pick $x$ to have the largest possible nilpotency index $m$ (meaning $x^{m-1}\neq 0=x^m$). But then $x$ cannot have a square root, for any such square root $y$ would satisfy $y^{2m-2}\neq 0=y^{2m}$, so would be nilpotent of index at least $2m-1>m$.

Therefore we have a reduced finite-dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb C$. Such an algebra is necessarily isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb C$, see for instance Proposition 1.5.6 in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups".

Comment: The problem is this a proof for simple algebra's such as (some*) associative algebra's. But for more exotic types like for instance complicated counterintuitive nonassociative ones that are not powerassociative and without unique inverses this is not clear.
* Also notice that by making the complex numbers a subalgebra you are restricting to even dimensions.

Comment: For the nilpotent $x$ you make some assumptions, just because $y$ is nilpotent at a higher index does not mean it can not exist. Powerassocitivity is not necc assumed for instance.

Comment: Apologies, for me "algebra" always means an associative one, so I assumed that to be the case. You may want to clarify you don't assume that in your question.